# Remove margin and padding for bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to span an image to the full width on my website and I noticed that the container, where the image is put into, has 150px margin and 15px padding automatically on the left and right side, so the image is displayed in the center. I have tried various ways of removing it but nothing worked, does anyone have a solution for that yet?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
            <img src="../../assets/business.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="business">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Drop the usage of `.container`, or even `.container-fluid`
2. Remove nagative margins from `.row` and the horizontal padding from all immediate columns by adding the class `.no-gutters`

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 mb-5">
        <img />
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/epw2vc8g/8/

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nopadding {

   padding: 0 !important;

   margin: 0 !important;

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-8 nopadding">
```

Reference:https://intellipaat.com/community/27892/remove-padding-from-columns-in-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

Use `.container-fluid` this will keep the container the full width of the window then add `.m-0.p-0` for no margin or padding on the container, row, and col. Then use `.w-100` on the `img` for 100% width.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
  <div class="row m-0 p-0">
    <div class="col-12 m-0 p-0 mb-5">
      <img src="https://www.k2bindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/bootstrap-1.jpg" class="w-100" alt="business">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```